# Using Cmake to generate C++ Visual Studio project

Tags: c++, algorithm, ubuntu, visual-studio-2013, cmake

So this is a tricky problem I have. I have an open source object tracking algorithm that runs well on Windows using Visual Studios 2013. Now, I have another algorithm using stereo vision that output two images, but this is done in Ubuntu using Cmake. My goal is to output this two images and pass them through the object tracking code.

What I want first is to make the algorithm that runs in Windows, work using cmake in Ubuntu. For this I guess I will need a CMakelists.txt for the path files. Might this be possible? The code do object color tracking using a monocamera connected to the PC. What should I do?

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Download [cmake for windows](https://cmake.org/download/) and use its GUI. Watch tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lAiuLHy4dCk)

Comment: ***Might this be possible?*** Yes of course, I use `CMake` to generate Visual Studio projects daily.